# Why does grid::grid.grabExpr try to open an X11 connection, and how can I prevent it?

Tags: r, x11

1. On Linux, run `DISPLAY= R`, then issue `grid::grid.grabExpr(1)`. This works fine, so `grid::grid.grabExpr` does not need an X11 connection.
2. Run `DISPLAY=XYZ R` and issue the same command. I am now getting

   ```
   Error in .External2(C_X11, d$display, d$width, d$height, d$pointsize,  :
     unable to start device X11cairo
   In addition: Warning message:
   In (function (display = "", width, height, pointsize, gamma, bg,  :
     unable to open connection to X11 display ''
   Calls: <Anonymous> -> dev.set -> <Anonymous>
   ```

Why does `grid::grid.grabExpr` try to open an X11 connection when it does not need one?

Context: some R code which absolutely should not depend on X11 connection fails to run when I shutdown my X11 server, and I would like to make the code robust towards this happening.

Bonus question: Run `DISPLAY=XYZ R`, then issue `Sys.unsetenv("DISPLAY"); grid::grid.grabExpr(1)`. I am getting the same error. The only difference between 1. and 2. being set variable `DISPLAY`, why does unsetting `DISPLAY` not take me back to the result of 1?

Comment: Related to the bonus question: https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2015-May/071100.html

Comment: And I think the answer to the first question is closely related to the fact that with a working X11 connection, `grid::grid.grabExpr(1)` opens an empty X11 window titled "R Graphics"...

Comment: I checked https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/1204d64c7afd07023a887aac2dd4bb97324d5dd0/src/library/grid/R/grab.R#L224-L236 and interestingly, running similar code (`pdf(file=NULL); grid:::grabDL()`) manually does not open an X11 windows/does not fail, while `grid:::grabDL()` on its own does. It is as if the call to `device(width, height)` was ineffective for some reason when run from the compiled package...

Comment: And the behavior is the same on Windows, except that X11 cannot fail because it is never tried. But a new window opens both for `grid::grid.grabExpr(1)` and for `grid:::grabDL()` but not for `pdf(file=NULL); grid:::grabDL()`.

Comment: Whatever is happening there, `R.devices::suppressGraphics(grid::grid.grabExpr(1))` works around it.